# How to make a discord bot display errors properly?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def wiki(ctx, *, arg1):
    try:
        try:
            page = wikipedia.page(arg1, auto_suggest=False, redirect=True, preload=False)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=page.title, color=0xE34234, url=page.url, description=page.summary)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
            await ctx.send(f":no_entry_sign: **No pages found for '{arg1}'!**")
            return
    except discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument:
        await ctx.send(":no_entry_sign: **Check `&bothelp` to learn how to use the command properly!**")
        return
```

If I enter a search query, that does not exist, in this Wikipedia search command, then my bot says `No pages found for '{arg1}'!`.

And if I don't enter any search query, then it does not display anything!
In the terminal it displays: `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument`.

Please, help me display these errors correctly to the user, if any of these two errors occur!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument` occur because your `arg1` is empty. To make it pass or you can empty the argument change it to `arg1 = None`. So the machine won't make any error if you don't search it. And for your first problem, sometimes `wikipedia.py` not recognize some alphabet perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The argument parsing happens before your try/except block can catch it, so you'll need to handle the exception another way.

You can add a default argument as mentioned in the comments:

```py
@bot.command()
async def wiki(ctx, *, arg1: str = None):
    if arg1 is None:
        await ctx.send(':no_entry_sign: **Missing required argument; check `&bothelp` to learn how to use the command properly!**')
        return
    # do stuff
```

Or add [a custom error handler for the command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#discord.ext.commands.Command.error):

```py
@wiki.error
async def wiki_error(self, ctx, err):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(':no_entry_sign: **Missing required argument; check `&bothelp` to learn how to use the command properly!**')
```

(Keep in mind that if you have a cog-level or bot-level error handler, it will be invoked with that too.)